# Trouble applying a simple template

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I'm having trouble applying a template to my checkboxes.  I have the following template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TriStateRed" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}" >
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Data" Value="M 0 2.5 A 5 2.5 0 1 1 5 5 L 5 8 M 5 10 L 5 10" />
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, visual studio gives me the following error:

> Cannot find the Trigger target 'path'.
>   (The target must appear before any
>   Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that
>   use it.)

Can anyone make sense of this?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for an element(control) named "path" inside the ControlTemplate. You need to have such element inside ControlTemplate in order to get this trigger working.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you want to create a border around your checkbox when IsChecked is null, but you haven't actually defined a Path element with the name "path".

Answer (score 0):

It means WPF does not know what is `"path"` in `Setters`.

When you define `ControlTemplate` triggers like this, you need to specify visual elements that constitute checkbox and then name one of those elements `"path"` and then triggers will know on what element they are applied.

This looks to me like example code from MSDN magazine article: [Using Templates to Customize WPF Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx). If this is so, you must use code from both Figure 1 and Figure 2 to have functioning CheckBox. There is code available for download or online browsing. Here is checkbox template: [`BigCheckBox.xaml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164525.aspx?code=true&level=root&file=BigCheckCheckBox.xaml)

There is [CheckBox ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=VS.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Also, check this StackOverflow questions:

- [WPF: Can I restyle a checkbox template, so that the checkindicator is a red cross instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305220/wpf-can-i-restyle-a-checkbox-template-so-that-the-checkindicator-is-a-red-cross)
- [Custom Checkbox style for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636653/custom-checkbox-style-for-wpf)